# How to change to log in with password in 17-10.1?

Tags: passwd

I installed Ubuntu 17.10.1 to log in automatically without password. I would now want to set a password for logging in . I tried to do this but after change  could not log in . How to do this properly? here is photo of my  screen.
[screen photo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lAUlI5xoEI4KdsT4yBKKzjptBhwYPaJ_/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article https://www.maketecheasier.com/enable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu/ where it is explained how to do on different DE.